# Echo variable variable from php snippet onto wordpress page

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have WordPress page and on it I have a php snippet added. After the snippet i have added an html block and i am trying to echo out values of variables that i have set in the php snippet.

I am using php snippet xyz

this is what my snippet contains for simplicity :

```
<?php
global $searchTopic;
$searchTopic = $_GET['topic_name']; // ex: topic_name = "home search"
```

I know the snippet is working fine and variable does have a value.
below the snippet i have this html code block

```
<div class="row">
   <label>Search</label>
   <input type="text" value="'.$searchTopic.'"/>
</div>
```

When i run the page to view the outcome i see an input field and the value is `'.$searchTopic.'`

How can i access and properly echo variables that i have set in a php snippet on a WordPress page?

Comment: Are you getting a plain `<input type="text" value="'.$searchTopic.'"/>` in your output? If so, try `<input type="text" value="<?=$searchTopic?>"/>`

Answer (score 1):

You must escape the value to avoid HTML injection.

Check this function: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_attr/

```
<div class="row">
    <label>Search</label>
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($searchTopic); ?>"/>
</div>
```